# Java 2D array (rectangular matrix) sum path of diagonal moves until you hit a wall, repeat until you hit a corner

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need help with the following problem, I've been stuck on it for 2 whole days.

"I am given the numbers a and b. They form a matrix of the powers of 2. You start from the top left corner of the matrix and go with diagonal moves, until you hit a wall. When a wall is hit, you change direction. You do this, until the direction cannot be changed anymore, i.e. you hit a corner. Find the sum of this path."

So far I created the matrix, filled it with numbers and created 2 booleans for 1.when you hit a corner and 2. when you hit a wall. 
I had several ideas how to continue, but none worked out.

```
for (int row = 0; row < a; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < b; col++) {

                boolean cornerHit = (row == 0 && col == 0) || (row == 0 && col == b - 1) ||
                        (row == a - 1 && col == b - 1) || (row == a - 1 && col == 0);

                boolean hitWall = (row == 0 && (col > 0 && col < b - 1)) ||
                        (col == 0 && (row > 0 && row < a - 1)) ||
                        (row == a - 1 && (col > 0 && col < b - 1)) ||
                        (col == b - 1 && (row > 0 && row < a - 1));
```

Example: if a=3 and b=4.

[here is what the matrix and the diagonal movement looks like for a =3, b=4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BAxW.jpg)
The path will be 1 4 16 16 4 4 4 and the sum 49. 
Please help! :))

Comment: Do you mind to draw the solution of what you wish to obtain? Then, scan it (or take a picture) and add it to your question. It will be easier to help out.

Comment: @acarlstein thanks for the recommendation, I uploaded a picture of a matrix and the movement :)

Comment: @kai thanks for the different idea! I will try it like this now, hope I do better, it sounds simpler :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is quite simple. 
In essence you should walk until you reach a corner.  That is a do/while construct.

We start in top left corner, so our start position is posx=0 and posy=0.
In every step we should move one(1) to the right and one down(1) so in x direction we have a deltax=1 and in the 
y direction a deltay=1 for every move.

If a wall is hit we should change direction.

A wall in y direction is hit if posy=0(top) or posy is size-1(botom column) in that case the deltay changes its sign: deltay = -deltay.

Same for x: A wall in x direction is hit if posx=0(left) or posx is size-1(rightmost column) in that case the deltax changes its sign: deltax = -deltax.

For simplicity i did the sizex-1 and sizey-1 right at the the beginning(sizex--; sizey--;) so the test just checks for size.

This should stop when we hit a corner, that is when we hit walls in y and x direction.

I added a boolean that prints the individual steps if set to true.

[Maybe you want to add an additional check for invalid rectangles like diagonalWalk(-1,-1)]

```
public static int diagonalWalk(int sizex, int sizey, boolean showSteps) {
    int posx = 0;
    int posy = 0;
    int sum = 1;
    int deltay = 1;
    int deltax = 1;
    sizex--;//valid cols are: 0 - sizex-1
    sizey--;//valid rows are: 0 - sizey-1
    if (showSteps) {
        System.out.println("At: 0/0:1");
    }
    do {
        posx += deltax;
        posy += deltay;
        sum += Math.pow(2, posx) * Math.pow(2, posy);
        if (showSteps) {
            System.out.println("At: " + posy + "/" + posx + ":" + Math.pow(2, posx) * Math.pow(2, posy));
        }

        //wallhit left or right
        if (posx == 0 || posx >= sizex) {
            deltax = -deltax;
        }
        //wallhit top or bottom
        if (posy == 0 || posy >= sizey) {
            deltay = -deltay;
        }
    }while(!((posx == 0 || posx >= sizex) && (posy == 0 || posy >= sizey)));
    return sum;
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int sum = diagonalWalk(3,4, true);
    System.out.println("result is:" + sum);
}
```

example run:

```
At: 0/0:1
At: 1/1:4.0
At: 2/2:16.0
At: 3/1:16.0
At: 2/0:4.0
At: 1/1:4.0
At: 0/2:4.0
result is:49
```

Comment: This is so brilliant! I am extremely thankful for your effort and time, going through the problem for a 5th time your solution makes sense and is so much simpler than any direction I went in with 1000 lines of code. It helped me a lot to understand the material. If I could, I would happily buy you a virtual beer/box of chocolates :)))