# Can't find the logic to solve this problem, any advices?

Tags: python, algorithm, loops, for-loop

I have one task that is a little bit difficult to me, so I am sharing the whole condition and hope this makes sense to you:

You are given numbers N and M. They form a matrix of the powers of 2.

Example: N = 3, M = 4

```
1  2  4  8

2  4  8 16

4  8 16 32
```

Starting from the top left corner of the matrix, Go with diagonal moves, until you hit a wall. When a wall is hit change direction. You do this, until the direction cannot be changed, i.e. you hit a corner.

Example:

If you have the above matrix, the path will be: 1 4 16 16 4 4 4

You task is to find the sum of this path.

Input
Read from the standard input

On the single line of the input, read the numbers N and M

Output
Print to the standard output

On the single line of the output, print the sum of the path

Sample tests

Input

```
3 4
```

Output

```
49
```

This is the code that I wrote by myself:

```
N = input("Enter the numbers").split(" ")

RowCol = []

for i in N:
    RowCol.append(int(i))

matrix = []

for i in range(RowCol[0]):
    row = []
    for j in range(RowCol[1]):
        row.append(2**(i + j))
    matrix.append(row)

for inner in matrix:
    print(inner)

result = []

for i in range(RowCol[0]):
    result.append(matrix[i][i])

print(RowCol)

print("Diagonal elements:", result)
```

I got to that point that I got the matrix, but I don't know how to make the rest of the condition. (Also I wrote loop that gives the diagonal, but I am not sure if this is helpful.)

I hope the task condition make sense about what is needed!

I tried almost everything, but I can't find any logic and way to do it, so you are my last hope!

I will be thankful for every advice or help!

Comment: Do you want the sum of the numbers you enter

Comment: No, I don’t need the sum of the numbers that I entered (if you mean the inputs 3  and 4 that tells the number of the rows and columns).

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54963235 (but there are better ways to solve this)

Comment: Does the condition makes sense at all? 

Comment: What is the `result` list for? It doesn't seem to be related to the problem at all.

Comment: I just tried different things...

Comment: Incomplete question in the explanation. Two values must be entered, not a set of values

Comment: It seems like you're asking us to do your homework for you. Creating the matrix is the easy part, the real task is the code that walks the path, and you haven't made any attempt at that.

Comment: See the question linked to above. It's in Java, but the answer explains the logic, you should be able to implement that in Python.

Comment: The solution and logic is there, he just has to convert the code into Python language

Comment: Where does this problem come from? There is an O(max(N, M)) solution, but it involves some math and might be too advanced if it's a CS101 type of homework

Comment: What are the maximum values of M and N?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to use current coordinates and directions for both axis: horizontal (`dir_h`) and vertical (`dir_v`).

The step is to add directions to both coordinates if that makes sence and change directions otherwise. If we are in a corner - stop.

You also don't have to precompute the matrix, because the value is always a simple function of the coordinates: `2 ** (i + j)`.

```
N, M = 3, 4

# initial position and directions
i, j = 0, 0
dir_v, dir_h = 1, 1

# adding starting element of the path
path = [2 ** (i + j)]

while True:
    # if we can perform step without going out of the matrix - doing it
    while i + dir_v < N and i + dir_v >= 0 and j + dir_h < M and j + dir_h >= 0:
        i += dir_v
        j += dir_h
        print(i, j)
        path.append(2 ** (i + j))
    
    # finish conditions
    if (i, j) in [(0, 0), (N - 1, 0), (0, M - 1), (N - 1, M - 1)]:
        break
    
    # deciding which way to turn
    if j != M - 1 and j != 0:
        dir_v *= -1
    else:
        dir_h *= -1
        
    print("directions:", dir_h, dir_v)
    
print(path)
```

Output:

```
1 1
2 2
directions: 1 -1
1 3
directions: -1 -1
0 2
directions: -1 1
1 1
2 0
[1, 4, 16, 16, 4, 4, 4]
```

Comment: Write the code in the form function

Answer (score 0):

You can progress through the coordinate pairs by cycling over the increasing and decreasing patterns that each coordinate takes as it bounces on edges.  For example, 4 columns will progress in the following pattern: 0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 2 ,... witch is a repetition of the 0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1 series over and over.   Rows and columns will each have their own cycles and you can stop when the row/column reaches a corner (after the initial 0,0).

Here is an example of a generator function that implements this logic:

```
def diagPath(rows,cols):
    ir = [*range(rows),*range(rows-2,0,-1)]
    ic = [*range(cols),*range(cols-2,0,-1)]
    for i in range(rows*cols):
        r,c = ir[i%len(ir)], ic[i%len(ic)]
        yield 2**(r+c)
        if i and (r+1,c+1) in ((1,1),(rows,1),(1,cols),(rows,cols)):
            break
```

output:

```
print(*diagPath(3,4))

1 4 16 16 4 4 4
```

*You can adapt the function to compute the sum directly instead of yielding the values on the path or just use `sum(diagPath(3,4))`*.

You could also compute the (one-based) row and column values mathematically instead of using lists:

```
def diagPath(rows,cols):
    for i in range(rows*cols):
        r = rows-abs(1-rows + i%(rows*2-2 or 1))
        c = cols-abs(1-cols + i%(cols*2-2 or 1))
        yield 2**(r+c-2)
        if i and (r,c) in ((1,1),(rows,1),(1,cols),(rows,cols)):
            break
```